# Why am I getting Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures. error?

Tags: angular

Hi I have this angular component code.

```
  private approvals: Approval[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsersApprovals(this.userid);
  }

  getUsersApprovals(userid) {
    this.approvalsService.getUsersApprovals(userid).subscribe(
      data  => this.getSuccess(data),
      error => this.getError(error)
    );
  }

 private getSuccess(data) {
    this.approvals = data;
    let approval_count = this.approvals.length;
  }
```

And when I execute `this.approvals.length` I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:

I was able to archive the affect I wanted by doing this instead ...

```
let approval_count = data.length;
```

... but I still don't understand what was wrong with:

```
    let approval_count = this.approvals.length;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `execute this.approvals.length`?

Comment: Can you show your your whole component and service code?

Comment: In `getUsersApprovals`, try `data  => console.log(data)` to see if `data` is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing what this ...

```
let approval_count = data.length;
```